# How to add a page-link/menu-item in template header navbar menu section by hooks wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to add a menu-item/page-link in the template navbar section by hooks from a plugin file.I do not want to use any plugin for this.I want to use hook.I have tried those after googling:

```
add_action('wp_header', ' xx_add_to_header');
 function xx_add_to_header() {  


 echo "<li><a href='king.php'>DDD</a> </li>";
     }
```

Another one :

```
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
  your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
     if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '<li><a href='king.php'>DDD</a></li>';
     }
    return $items;    
    }
```

its did not work.What is the right way to do this????
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think shortcode will solve my problems.I am new wordpress.I did not know about shortcode of wordpress.